# SQL get number of items with sales over certain quantity

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Using SQL Server

I have a database table which tracks all the transactions in a store.

The following query gives me a list of item IDs where the items have sales over a certain quantity:

```
select
    ItemID
    , SUM(Quantity)
from
     TransactionEntry 
group by
        ItemID
Having 
    Sum(Quantity) >3500
```

There are 5 such items:

| ItemID | (No column name) |
| --- | --- |
| 7543 | 4558 |
| 6484 | 7242 |
| 6482 | 4145 |
| 6617 | 3931 |
| 6486 | 4499 |

However, I cannot for the life of me figure out how to get simply 5 - that is, how many items have sales of more than 3500 units? I know this is something simple but I cannot see it. If I try:

```
select
    Count(ItemID)
from
     TransactionEntry 
Having 
    Sum(Quantity) >3500
```

I get an answer - 241010! Very definitely not 5!!

Please show what I'm doing wrong!

Comment: Please don't add personal "fluff" in your question. Keep them concise and to the point.

Comment: please define " personal "fluff"" Dale K

Comment: @GrahamH any noise that doesn't add actual information to the question see [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260776/should-i-remove-fluff-when-editing-questions/261002#261002)

Comment: Huh?   Dale please clearly mark each "fluff word" in the OP post....may make some sense then.
Cheers

Comment: `Count(ItemID)` doesn't mean "how many `ItemID` are there" it means "how many rows are there in the grouping where `ItemID` is not null" and in this case the grouping is the whole table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way of achieving the same would be

```
select Sum(over3500) from (
    select Iif(Sum(Quantity)>3500,1,0) over3500
    from TransactionEntry 
    group by ItemID
)s
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a subquery:

```
select count(*)
from (select ItemID, SUM(Quantity)
      from TransactionEntry 
      group by ItemID
      having Sum(Quantity) > 3500
     ) i;
```

Comment: I knew it was simple! D'oh!! Thanks

Comment: Sorry - accidental